# only left border in textdocument

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I am trying to draw only the left border in QTextDocument. Since afaik QTextFrame doesn't support selective border so I am trying with assigning a textured brush to the text frame. Something like the following -

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextFrameFormat>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextFrame>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextDocument doc;
    QPixmap map(1024, 1024);
    QPainter p;
    p.begin(&map);
    p.setBackground(QBrush(Qt::transparent));
    p.drawRect(QRect(0,0, 4, map.height()));
    p.end();

    QTextFrameFormat frameFormat;
    QBrush bruh(map);
    bruh.setColor(Qt::transparent);
    frameFormat.setBackground(bruh);
    auto cur = new QTextCursor(&doc);
    auto frame = cur->insertFrame(frameFormat);
    auto curf = new QTextCursor(frame);
    curf->insertText("Hello this is qt program!");

    QTextEdit e;
    e.setDocument(&doc);
    e.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But this prints a black background even though the background is set to be transparent(I need a transparent background with only left red border).
I can't figure out what is wrong. Also, can there be any other way to have only a left border to a QTextFrame?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QTextDocument doc;
QPixmap map(1024, 1024);
map.fill(Qt::white);
QPainter p;
p.begin(&map);
p.fillRect(QRect(0,0, 4, map.height()),QBrush(Qt::red));
p.end();
```

Comment: If you do not use qss styling then better use pallete color to fill pixmap. So use `map.fill(e.palette().color(QPalette::Base));` not `map.fill(Qt::white);`. Also maybe you want to add paddings to move your text from border. Then use `frameFormat.setPadding(4);`

Answer (score 1):

For example,

TextEdit.h

```
#ifndef TEXTEDIT_H
#define TEXTEDIT_H

#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QTextFrame>

class TextEdit: public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:


    explicit TextEdit(QObject* parent=nullptr);


    void drawFrames(QPainter &p, QTextFrame* f);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);

};

#endif // TEXTEDIT_H
```

TextEdit.cpp

```
#include "TextEdit.h"
#include <QAbstractTextDocumentLayout>
#include "qpainter.h"

TextEdit::TextEdit(QObject* parent)
{

}


void TextEdit::drawFrames(QPainter& p, QTextFrame* f)
{
    QRectF rf = document()->documentLayout()->frameBoundingRect(f);
    rf = QRectF(rf.left(), rf.top(), 1, rf.height());

    QPen pen = p.pen();
    QBrush brush = p.brush();
    pen.setWidth(1);
    pen.setColor(Qt::red);
    brush.setColor(Qt::red);
    p.setPen(pen);
    p.setBrush(brush);

    p.drawRect(rf);

    QList<QTextFrame*> lf = f->childFrames();
    foreach (QTextFrame* cf , lf)
    {
        drawFrames(p, cf);
    }


}

void TextEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    QTextDocument * doc = document();
    QTextFrame* rootFrame = doc->rootFrame();
    QPainter p = QPainter(viewport());
    drawFrames(p, rootFrame);
    QTextEdit::paintEvent(e);

}

void TextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{

    if (e->key() == Qt::Key_1)
    {
        QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
        QTextFrameFormat f;
        f.setLeftMargin(5);
        tc.insertFrame(f);
        return;
    }

    QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "TextEdit.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TextEdit e;
    e.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Please press 1 to insert a new frame.

[image]